# Find entries of symbols in any order

Tags: python, regex

I need to filter all strings that includes one or more digits, one or more uppercase symbols and one or more lowercase symbols.

I created next regex statement: `[0-9]+[A-Z]+[a-z]+`. It works pretty much as I want, but with some problems. It filters strings only if they have digit, uppercase, lowercase one by one and only in this order. I know that must be some fix to specify like "find this substrings in any part of string and in any order". But I cannot find this in docs.

There are some examples:

```
input: d23de32 output: false
input: ffFF88 output: true
input: ferGr444 output: true
input: 12343534 output: false
input: AAAA444 output: false
```

P.S. I don't know is it important or not, but problem is in the regex in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookahead here,

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).*$
```

To match only alphanumeric strings.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vX0aJ9/2)

```
(?=.*?[A-Z]) - Positive lookahead is used here which asserts that the input must contain an uppercase letter.
(?=.*?[a-z]) - Asserts that the input contains a lowercase letter.
(?=.*?[0-9]) - Asserts that the input contains a digit.
```

Comment: the `?` after `.*` is redundant - the expression `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$` works just as well.

Comment: I tested this and it works, but could you explain what it mean?) I know ^ - start, $ - end, but what mean ?=.*? ?

Comment: @isedev `?` helps to reduce the steps. Click on the regex debugger in the above link.

Comment: @AvinashRaj nice one, hadn't realised that before.

Comment: @Crabar lookarounds in regex are acts like conditions. so first the pattern `(?=.*?[A-Z])` would be checked. If it's true then it checks the next pattern `(?=.*?[a-z])`. If it's false then it skips that corresponding line. It matches the string only if all the above three conditions are satisfied.